# Integrate facebook account with user account in my iOS application

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm using Facebook iOS SDK 4.0 in my iOS application. I want to integrate Facebook accounts with the user profile of my application. It is used for sharing purpose and I want the integration to be maintained for the user across multiple devices. As remote token cache was deprecated in Facebook iOS SDK 4.4, is it safe that I save the Facebook access token to my server directly through a web service? Is there any method I should follow in saving so? It would be very helpful if you provide some sample code.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by '.. I want the integration to be maintained for the user across multiple device'.

Comment: @Bangdel, that means I want the access token to be saved in server, so that once the user logs in my application in one device using Facebook, I can use the token, for Facebook sharing, when he logs in my application in another device. I just want the steps and terms to be followed in saving the Facebook access token in my server.

Comment: Here's a nice bit of documentation that might be able to help you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension